# Firebase Objective C API update value without download

Tags: objective-c, firebase

I'm using Firebase iOS API to create a desktop application running on OS X.
However I found a weird behavior that the iOS API doesn't do the same thing as Firebase's JavaScript library.

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://*****.firebaseio.com");
var aaaRef = ref.child("AAA/aaa");
aaaRef.update({"name":"helloworld"});
```

I inspect the websocket frames through Google Chrome developer tool,
It just send without receiving the updated data from server.
So I only UPLOAD the object and get a successful "ok" returned.

If I convert the above code into ObjC,

```
ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"https://*****.firebaseio.com"];
Firebase* aaaRef = [ref childByAppendingPath:@"AAA/aaa"]
[aaaRef updateChildValues:@{@"name":@"helloworld"}];
```

It will both UPLOAD and DOWNLOAD the data from the server.

As you can see the network io in the following screenshot:
In every seconds, Receiving = Sending, and if I send larger content, it receives the same amount of data too.

**Screenshot** https://i.stack.imgur.com/7K141.png
(I'm new to StackOverflow, and it says I can't post images)

I know in the official API docs, there's an optional parameter for updateChildValues **withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error, Firebase *ref)**

It seems that with this block, *ref will receive the updated value from Firebase.
And updateChildValues without **withCompletionBlock**, just pass an empty block internally so it shares the same method in Firebase's iOS API.

I don't want to make that happen. I want the same behavior with Javascript Library.
I hope someone can guide me how to do that.

Comment: I found **setValue** has the same problem.

Comment: The internal implementation details vary a bit from one Firebase client to another. This includes how each client library manages its cache. 

If you think this might be a bug in the Objective C client library, you should ping the support team at Firebase per https://www.firebase.com/docs/help/

Comment: This is a bug report which does not ask for a workaround or cite a specific question and should be reported to the vendor (i.e. support at Firebase).